# Solving for an unknown matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

Solve for $X$:

[image: Solve for X]

$$
\left[ \begin{array}{cc}
2 & 5 \\
0 & 0 \\
\end{array} \right ] - X \left [ \begin{array}{cc}
-7 & 8 \\
7 &  -7 \\
\end{array} \right ] \;\;=\;\; I
$$
$X$ is an unknown $2\times 2$ matrix.

I'm not exactly sure how to solve for this matrix. I know that $I$ stands for a matrix multiplied by the inverse matrix, but I do not know which one. Could someone help me out on this?

Comment: Something seems wrong.  If $I$ is the identity matrix then the equation presented doesn't make sense.

Comment: Hmmmmmmmm why ?

Comment: @krirkrirk Nevermind.  The entries in the $2\times 2$ arrays were so close together they looked like columns at a first glance.  I submitted an edit so that the equation looks clearer.

Comment: The fact that neither '7-7' and 00 are valid numbers could have help you :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$I$ stands for the identity matrix, i.e.  $$I = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$$ Write $$ X = \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d\end{pmatrix}$$ and then you just have to find $a,b,c,d$ by remembering how to multiply matrixes.

Comment: THANK YOU! Once I figured out that "I" was for the identity matrix, I was able to figure it out